# Сравнить элемент словаря со всеми элементами другого словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть 2 словаря: Train и Test, у которых одинаковые ключи.

Словарь Train:

```
Train: = {Key1: [A, B, C], Key2: [D, E, F], Key3: [G, H, I]}
```

Словарь Test:

```
Test = {Key1: [J, K], Key2: [L, M], Key3: [O, P]}
```

Мне необходимо сравнить каждый элемент в словаре Test со всеми элементами всех ключей словаря Train.
Другими словами, надо найти дистанцию по алгоритму между матрицами, коими и являются элементы словарей.

То есть:
J сравнивается с A, получаем число, потом J с B, J с C, а далее нужно перейти в следующий ключ словаря Train и сравнить уже J с D и так далее. В конце J сравнивается с I и после этого сравниваем элемент K словаря Test со всеми элементами словаря Train.

Я пробовал следующий код:

```
for class in Train:
    dist[class] = []      
    for Test1 in Test[class]:
        this_row = []
        for Train1 in Train[class]:
            ("some func" dist = dist(Train1, Test))
            this_row.append(dist)
        Ddis[class].append(this_row)
```

При этом, я сравниваю элементы только внутри 1 ключа, что не решает мою проблему. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

Comment: В ваших реальных данных используются строки или числа? И какая метрика используется для измерения дистанции? Укажите что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: В реальных данных каждый элемент в словарях - матрица.
Метрика по которой измеряется дистанция - это алгоритм DTW (динамическая трансформация шкалы времени), на вход его берутся 2 матрицы (в одномерном варианте 2 вектора), на выходе получается дистанция между 2 матрицами.
Что касается моего вопроса - на выходе хочу получить матрицу расстояний, где ряды - это элементы словаря Test, а столбцы - элементы словаря Train

Comment: Лучше будет если вы приведёте пример данных более приближённый к вашим реальным данным (конечно в уменьшенном варианте). Если я вас правильно понял, то ваши данные могут быть представлены как 3D матрица - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Если вкратце - то задача распознавания слов при помощи метода DTW. Произнесенное слово разбивается на фреймы (M фреймов по 20 мс), и при обработке каждого фрейма я получаю MFCC вектор (N коэффициентов MFCC). Так, каждое слово представляется как матрица размером (N x M), причем N - всегда постоянное, а M - меняется (длительность слов разная). Поэтому и DTW, что он высчитывает разницу между разной длиной произношения. Итого я получаю обучающую и тестовую выборку из 3 классов(ключей) по 3 элемента (произношения этого слова). Надо соотнести тестовое слово с обучающей выборкой - распознать слово.

Comment: Как правило количество фреймов варьируется от 20 до 45. Количество MFCC коэффициентов (специальная мера ощущения звука, переведенная в набор значений) 13 элементов.
Вообще в идеале было бы получить матрицу расстояний между тестовым словом и обучающим, и минимальное значение в строке будет означать класс, к которому принадлежит тестовое слово.

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в синтаксисе Питона. В моей попытке я смотрел цикл по ключам, и циклы по значениям ключей. А тут, мне надо взять элемент из тестовой выборки (то есть матрицу (13(MFCC)x 40(фреймы)) и сравнить с каждым элементом из обучающей, но тогда мне надо либо как-то игнорировать ключи, чтобы со всеми значениями работать как с вектором, либо использовать какие-то функции словарей, но тут пока не получается придумать как это реализовать.

Comment: Без конкретного примера описание выглядит немного абстрактно и не очень понятно. А нельзя ваши матрицы выпрямить, чтобы получить числовые ряды?

Comment: Матрицы выпрямлять не надо, потому что при сравнении элемента (матрицы 13x40) из тестовой выборки (записанное на диктофон слово, которое преобразовано в набор MFCC коэффициентов) с элементом(матрицей) обучающей выборки (то же слово но сказанное чуть по-другому) после алгоритма DTW получается число. Итого после сравнения каждого слова из тестовой выборки(3 тестовых произношения 5 слов) со всеми словами из обучающей выборки (по 5 произношений тех же 5 слов) получится матрица из чисел 15x25.
Да и в целом я думал абстрагироваться от предмета, и думал как    сравнить элементы в двух словарях.

Comment: Если сильно абстрагироваться, то в лучшем случае вам предложат алгоритм с вложенными циклами, который будет работать неприлично долго. Я думаю рано или поздно вам придется искать векторизированное решение...

Comment: А вообще, если есть 2 словаря- А и Б, есть ли возможность сравнивать (находить дистанцию)  элемент словаря А со всеми элементами словаря Б? Как с использованием, так и без использования ключей в словарях. В моей реализации я это могу  делать только внутри каждого ключа, что плохо

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Также советую ознауомиться с ["Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подумав сегодня над задачей пришел к следующему решению:

```
Ddist = dict()
for class_nameTest in Test:
    Ddist[class_nameTest] = []
    for Test1 in Test[class_nameTest]: 
        this_row = []
        for class_nameTrain in Train:  
            for Train1 in Train[class_nameTrain]:
                np.random.seed(777) # Для одинаковых результатов у пользователей
                dist = np.linalg.norm(Train1 - Test1) #Вместо DTW будем вычислять норму матриц
                this_row.append(dist)
        Ddist[class_nameTest].append(this_row)
```

В итоге получается словарь, где ключи - классы, а элементы в ключах - векторы из чисел, отражающие дистанцию между матрицами (или касаясь моей задачи - мера близости между тестовым словом и всеми словами из обучающей выборки). Далее стояла задача найти минимальное значение вектора в каждом элементе каждого ключа. При этом я нашел индекс минимального элемента и он равен порядковому номеру элемента в обучающей выборке, но без привязки к ключу.

```
MinDist = dict()
MinIndex = dict()     
for class_name in Ddist:
    this_rowMin = []
    this_rowIndex = []
    MinDist[class_name] = []
    MinIndex[class_name] = []
    for test_class in Ddist[class_name]:
        Min = min(test_class)
        this_rowMin.append(Min)
        Index = test_class.index(min(test_class))
        this_rowIndex.append(Index)
    MinDist[class_name].append(this_rowMin)
    MinIndex[class_name].append(this_rowIndex)
```

В итоге я знаю, что элемент тестовой выборки имеет наименьшую дистанцию с каким-то элементом из обучающей выборки, знаю порядковый номер этого элемента обучающей выборки, но при этом не понимаю как можно ему сопоставить ключ(т.е. класс). Например, возьмем слово из тестовой выборки "Копировать2", у него минимальная дистанция с 3 элементом (индекс = 2), а 3 элемент это "Вставить3". 
 Как по номеру индекса минимального расстояния получить ключ словаря, если этот номер не привязан к словарю?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr 24 22:16:43 2018

@author: Rostislav
"""
import numpy as np

# =============================================================================
# Имитируем обучающие и тестовые выборки
# 5 раз произнесли слово "Вставить", обработали и получили 
# на выходе 5 фреймов по 4 уникальных коэффициента в каждом фрейме
# причем, 3 произношения будут относиться к обучающей выборке, а 2 к тестовой
# Все то же самое делаем со словами "Копировать" и "Открыть"
# =============================================================================
VstTrain1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
VstTrain2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
VstTrain3 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

KopTrain1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
KopTrain2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
KopTrain3 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

OtkTrain1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
OtkTrain2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
OtkTrain3 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

VstTest1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
VstTest2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

KopTest1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
KopTest2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

OtkTest1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))
OtkTest2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (4,5))

# =============================================================================
# Составим 2 словаря с одинаковыми ключами, где элементы словаря представлены
# матрицами, имитирующими обучающую и тестовую выборки
# =============================================================================
Train = {'Вставить':[VstTrain1, VstTrain2, VstTrain3],
         'Копировать':[KopTrain1, KopTrain2, KopTrain3],
         'Открыть':[OtkTrain1, OtkTrain2, OtkTrain3]}

Test = {'Вставить':[VstTest1, VstTest2],
        'Копировать':[KopTest1, KopTest2],
        'Открыть':[OtkTest1, OtkTest2]}

Ddist = dict()
for class_name in Train:
    Ddist[class_name] = []      
    for Test1 in Test[class_name]:
        this_row = []
        for Train1 in Train[class_name]:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(Train1 - Test1) #Вместо DTW будем вычислять норму матриц
            this_row.append(dist)
        Ddist[class_name].append(this_row)
```

В итоге я нахожу дистанцию (норму) между тестовой матрицей и всеми матрицами в обучающей выборке только внутри ключа, а надо чтобы сначала тестовая матрица нашла норму со всеми элементами обучающей выборки внутри первого ключа, потом нашла норму со всеми элементами обучающей выборки второго ключа и третьего ключа. Потом следующий элемент тестовой выборки (матрица VstTest2) снова ищет нормы по всем элементам всех ключей. И так со всей тестовой выборкой.
В итоге нужно получить либо матрицу 6x9 (6 тестовых слов(матриц) сравниваются с 9 словами(матрицами) из обучающей выборки), где элементы матрицы - расстояние между тестовым словом i и обучающим словом j, либо в циклах сохранять ключ при минимальной норме и соотносить тестовое слово (матрицу) с этим ключом.